# Feel good idiomatic expressions

Tags: idiomatic-language

What would be a more idiomatic way to say that tourists like my city and are usually happy with it when they come here?

Visitors who come to our city feel very good.

Comment: I've closed this because there are an infinite number of ways to rewrite your sentence with roughly the same meaning, and questions here must focus on one aspect of English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are any all-encompassing phrases that would cover the vast array of positive feelings different people may have about a place they visit. People may visit a city for its history, its attractions, its nightlife, or its food. So they may have a range of feelings such as excited, fascinated, awed, impressed etc.

It would be more logical, as well as more idiomatic, to report the evidence you have for making such a statement rather than try to state the feelings of so many different people. For example, I would expect to see claims such as "*the vast majority of visitors to our city rate their experience highly*", which would suggest some research has been done on a sample population of visitors and that the majority speak positively about their individual experience, no matter what their expectations were.

Comment: can I use feel very good in my sentence?

Comment: @AntoniaA No, your entire sentence is garbage.